# Spark Scala DataFrame to csv string

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Spark DataFrame that i know, fits in memory. I want to generate a csv representation as a string on the driver.

```scala
val df  = // Some DataFrame
val csv = // String Representation
```

I know that I can do

```scala
df.repartition(1)
  .write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .save("/your/location/mydata")
```

However, this saves the csv to disk as some random looking filename in the given folder.
Is there a way, to not write that Data to a File, but rather get it as a string or some other representation?

Answer (score 0):

A few ways... perhaps the easiest is to covert to a Pandas Dataframe and use that to write the CSV `df.toPandas().to_csv()`

Also seen this way used in Databricks that does not rely on Pandas but relies on Databricks `dbutils` which essentially moves and renames the file after it's written. Could be achieved with other libs such as boto3 for AWS S3 or similar for other storage tech,

```
file_location = f"{save_location}{name}.csv"

df.repartition(1).write.csv(path=csv_location, header="true")

file = dbutils.fs.ls(csv_location)[-1].path
dbutils.fs.cp(file, file_location)
dbutils.fs.rm(csv_location, recurse=True)
```

Comment: Just noted you are working in Scala, sorry, native Pandas example will not work for you. My best answer is therefore to modify the original spark output file by whatever appropriate means are available in your environment as per the above

Answer (score 0):

Below solution can give `String` represent data from `DataFrame` but may not give exact solution what you're looking for.

To get String represent data from Dataframe

Fetch `Row` from Dataframe using `map` method and convert to case class or use [tuple](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/tuples.html) values

Use `collect` method and convert it to String using `mkString()`

```
val csvStrRepresentData:String = df.map{row=>CsvCaseClass(row.getAs[Type]("col_name"),row.getAs[Type]("col_name"),...row.getAs[Type]("col_name"))}
.collect()
.mkString("\n")
```